# Sfml text goes beyond the bounds of screen

Tags: c++, sfml

I have this snippet of code

```
void Graphics::render_text(std::string bunch_of_text) {
    sf::Text text;
    text.setFont(font); // font is a sf::Font
    text.setString(bunch_of_text);
    text.setCharacterSize(text_size); // in pixels, not points!
    text.setFillColor(text_color);
    text.setStyle(text_style);
    window.draw(text);
    window.display();
}
```

And sometimes this text is really long, and the remainder of the text can't be seen because of bounds.
Is there an opportunity to make text perfectly fitting on the screen, such as splitting `text` into multiple parts or making a new line(`\n`) inside the `text` where needed?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one idea (pseudocode):

- While [`text.getLocalBounds().width`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Text.php#a3e6b3b298827f853b41165eee2cbbc66) > [`window.size().x`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1RenderWindow.php#ae3eacf93661c8068fca7a78d57dc7e14):

  - Determine an appropriate place in the text to add a newline.  Possibly use [`text.getCharacterSize()`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Text.php#a46d1d7f1d513bb8d434e985a93ea5224) and/or [`text.getLetterSpacing()`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Text.php#a028fc6e561bd9a0671254419b498b889) to do this calculation.
  - [`text.setString()`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Text.php#a7d3b3359f286fd9503d1ced25b7b6c33) to set the new string.